# Java - Trouble Accessing ValueMap

Tags: java

I've got a pretty simple script that simply accesses a resources properties via a ValueMap. Except for some reason I keep getting an **unexpected token error** were the if statement starts. This has to be something I'm just overlooking.

```
public class headerComponent{
  ValueMap property = resource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class);
  if(property != null) {
    pageHeader = property.get("pageHeader", "");
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `if` direct inside your **class**. This should be inside a **function**.

**For Ex:**

```
public class headerComponent{
  ValueMap property = resource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class);

public void getMeProp()
{
  if(property != null) {
    pageHeader = property.get("pageHeader", "");
  }
}

}
```

If you want to return your *string* then use `public String getMeProp()` and in the end of the function `return pageHeader`. Depends how you want to implement.

Comment: thanks @Ravi thought it was something simple I was just overlooking.